# A bounded function and lebesgue measurable sets.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f : [0, 1] \to {\mathbf R}$ be bounded.

(a) Show that the set where $f$ is continuous is Lebesgue measurable (even
if $f$ is not Lebesgue measurable).

(b) Show that if $f$ is not continuous on a set of full Lebesgue measure,
then $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

This is a old prelim question, which I have no idea how to start.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.